# Facebook 3.0 How to post wall?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

So the new facebook 3.0 [offers good guides for how to post on wall](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/). But what do you do when it doesn't fly?

I get following response from facebook:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) Missing message or attachment}, isFromCache:false}
```

Here is my permission update:

```
                Session session = ParseFacebookUtils.getSession();
                if(session != null) {

                    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                                .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                        return;
                    }

                    publishStory();
                }
```

PERMISSIONS has following:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
```

Here is my publish code which very much (not completely) is copy paste from facebook:

```
private void publishStory() {
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("name", "Test");
    postParams.putString("caption", "Another Test");
    postParams.putString("description", mEdit.getText().toString());

    Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                       .getGraphObject()
                                       .getInnerJSONObject(); //FIXME <-- here we get the error
            String postId = null;
            try {
                postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i(GlobalValues.LOG_TAG,
                    "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
            }
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                     .getApplicationContext(),
                     error.getErrorMessage(),
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                         .getApplicationContext(), 
                         postId,
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    Request request = new Request(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), "me/feed", postParams, 
                          HttpMethod.POST, callback);

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:

Here is a list of my permissions at request time:

```
[status_update, photo_upload, video_upload, create_note, share_item, publish_stream, publish_actions, basic_info]
```

Comment: `errorType: OAuthException` Seems like you have a problem with your authentification

Comment: @BenjaminSchwalb Suggested action?

Comment: I don´t know, never used FacebookSDK, just pointed it out, if you haven´t seen it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check for publish permissions? Code from link you posted checks for permissions before sending request.

```
    // Check for publish permissions    
    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        return;
    }
```

Edit:
    Try adding message parameter:

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("name", "Test");
postParams.putString("caption", "Another Test");
postParams.putString("description", mEdit.getText().toString());
postParams.putString("message", "My message");
```

Comment: Did you try adding key "message"? postParams.putString("message", "My message");

Comment: Where do you want me to add key?

Comment: Add it Bundle postParams, bellow other parameters.

Comment: Now why does adding "message" work when I have both name caption and description which doesn't get displayed at all :S I guess it's because I don't use link or image.

Comment: Facebook SDK can lack documentation some times.

Comment: Lack is such a small lacking word for my feelings toward facebook api